# How to use distinct on single column and return multiple other columns in bigquery?

Tags: sql, distinct-values

I have a bigquery table which has duplicate values and I would like to use distinct operator to remove those duplicates. But not getting expected output after executing below query.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    customerRefNo,
    custType,
    executionDate,
    Unit
FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable`
```

In my table there are duplicates of customerRefNo and would like to remove those. Any suggestion from anyone ?

Comment: Outside of the context of seeing your actual data, we may not be able to answer your question.  Please show the current and expected output.

Comment: Current data I am getting is :

Row  customerRefNo custType executionDate Unit 

1  23098                      single      2019-09-30      QA
2  23098                      single      2019-09-29      QA

Here I want distinct of customerRefNo, but when I use above query since the date is different for both records it gives me duplicates of customerRefNo as output. Basically this is a daily run job where executionDate is currentDate.

Comment: OK...so which date of many would you want to retain, and what is the logic behind that?

Comment: I want older date (2019-09-29) from this record. and the logic is that I have another complex query which stores some data into this table(which i am using in above query). I would like to make sure that when I query this table i should not get duplicates of customerRefNo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, the following `GROUP BY` query might be along the lines of what you want:

```
SELECT
    customerRefNo,
    custType,
    MAX(executionDate) AS executionDate,
    Unit
FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable`
GROUP BY
    customerRefNo,
    custType,
    Unit;
```